# Should I store a global counter or an aggregated value in a TSDB

Tags: time-series, influxdb

This question is really about the data schema. I have a program which has a bunch of discrete events, and I want to get beautiful graphs out.

- From my knowledge, I understand that I should really keep a counter of the number of events that have occurred, and on a regular interval, transfer that cumulative counter to the TSDB (as part of a cron job or similar).
- What I currently have though is a system where the monitor, on a regular interval, tells the TSB how many events occurred during that interval (a fixed hard coded value!).

Which of these two design patterns is better? What are the factors that affect that decision? Do I have a counter value here or is it just a measurement?

*I have various concerns, including but not limited to the efficiency of the monitoring tool*.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the question with InfluxDB but it seems like what you are really asking about is the collection agent.  For that I would look at Telegraf.

StatsD is also a really great lightweight API that is available for most major languages now, from which you can efficiently emit different types of stats (counters, timings, etc); either for every event or at a sample rate you define.

I implemented a solution that gather metrics emitted from my app using StatsD, metrics that were pulled (JMX queries), and basic host level stats you get for free with Telegraf.  Every host (30+) runs a single telegraf instance which delivers its stats to a centralized InfluxDB server on some interval (i.e. 30 seconds).

So with an approach like that you get a good balance of performance and data precision.

Comment: Hi - actually no, perhaps my question needs a reformat. I'm not interested in the technology to aggregate, I'm only interested in the way those metrics are stored inside the TSDB itself.

Comment: Well then you should collect data at whatever interval you need for your visualizations.  But understand that this technology stack is going to aggregate your data.  And the tools you pick to send your data to the TSDB will dictate how the aggregation happens, you can't totally separate the two.

Typically, you emit every event you care about from your system to some collection agent (i.e. Telegraf), where it gets aggregated/enriched/etc and fowarded onto the DB

Comment: I'm not sure this is still answering the fundamental question though as to which style to store, a running cumulative or a count of what was performed in the previous x minutes, or the benefits of either?

Comment: I think time-series data implies that you are collecting data points over time.  So the later, a count/timing/etc of something during some interval of time.

Comment: So thats still an opinion: this is my problem, all the resources on the internet don't show what is the *right* way backed with evidence. For instance, by storing a value of 'x happened in the last minute' then if the collection/aggregation tool pauses, effectively we loose data. Where as with a system which is collecting cumulative we just loose how we get to the total value, we don't actually lose any count. The older fashioned RRDB tools *all* worked off a cumulative (i.e. network packets in / out etc)